App is restarting when tap on notification in flutter
I am using infobip_mobilemessaging: ^6.1.1 for chat, and using its push notification. I updated my
/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml with application code of live chat widget here files looks like
<resources>
    <string name="infobip_application_code">application code here</string>
   
</resources>

updated app level build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation ('com.infobip:infobip-mobile-messaging-android-sdk:12.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Other dependencies
}


and project level build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'  // Set the Kotlin version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'  // Update this line
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

    }
}


here is my ChatPage




class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late Future<void> _initializeChatFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeChatFuture = _initializeChat();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeChat() async {
    await initialize();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    try {
      log('InfobipService initialized');

      await InfobipMobilemessaging.init(mmconfiguration.Configuration(
        applicationCode: 'application code here',
        inAppChatEnabled: true,
        fullFeaturedInAppsEnabled: false,
        defaultMessageStorage: true,
        privacySettings: mmconfiguration.PrivacySettings(
          userDataPersistingDisabled: false,
          carrierInfoSendingDisabled: false,
          systemInfoSendingDisabled: false,
        ),
      ));

      await InfobipMobilemessaging.registerForRemoteNotifications();

      InfobipMobilemessaging.on(
        LibraryEvent.notificationTapped,
        (Message message) {
          setState(() {
            AppStrings.isNotiTapped=true;
          });
        },
      );

    } catch (e) {
      log('Error initializing Infobip Mobile Messaging: $e');
      // Handle initialization error
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    log('AppStrings.isNotiTapped  ${AppStrings.isNotiTapped}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text('Chat Page'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeChatFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            log('DONE');

            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              if (mounted) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
                InfobipMobilemessaging.showChat();
              }
            });
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Chat is loading...'),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Error initializing chat'),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}




I am navigating to ChatPage from the home screen.
My app screens are
splashscreen
homescreen
chatpage
Problem:
So, the problem is when user navigate to the chatpage from homescreen and then navigate back, it redirects to the homescreen which is logically correct. but let say user is at homescreen now, and ontap on chat notification it loads the chat and when navigating back it redirect to the splashscreen, which is wrong. it should navigate to the homescreen.
Moreover, when i app killed and i tapped on notification it loads the chat, and when navigating back it comes to splashscreen. I have to add the user login condition too which checks if user is logged in then it opens the chat otherwise it comes to the splashscreen and then login screen.
What i understand is, when i remove the initialize  method it still load the chat but when i removed the application code from strings.xml file, chat is not loading.
UPDATE:
I found this documentation. but i am not getting how to use these solution on my code.
please help me to fix the issue.
